# Progress bar inconvertable types; cannot cast error

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I have implemented a progress bar within my activity XML layout but when i attempt to cast it within my activity class I receive the following error.

> inconvertible types; cannot cast android.view.View
>   com.project.Progress bar

I have researched this error but i am still unsure how to remedy it.

```
public class ProgressBar extends Activity{

    ProgressBar progressbar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress_bar);

        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}
```

activity_progress_bar.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:minWidth="220dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class has the same name as the widget `ProgressBar`. It is trying to cast `View` object to your class not to `android.widget.ProgressBar`

Either change the name of your class or provide full package name.

Comment: Thank you so much. I should of known - it is my first time using a progress bar and i was sure i was using in incorrectly in some way. I really appreciate your help!